# ASP.NET - Populate a page with input entered from a previous page

Tags: asp.net

on my website I have an "Enroll" page where users submit some basic information, there's some basic validation on that page then the user is taken to an "Enrollment Confirmed" page (which i don't want to display the info from previous page). On the confirmation page there is link to a "Print Enrollment Confirmation" page which, on this page, I want to contain the information entered from the "Enroll" page. So basically, I want the input entered on "Page 1" put into labels on "Page 3". I've seen some examples of transferring information from "Page 1" to "Page 2" but I have an extra page users need to go through before hitting the page with their previously entered data.

Can someone give me an explanation on how I could do this without using query strings? Thank you.

Comment: 9 options for managing state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

Comment: Just a quick clarification. If Page2 and Page3 are not heavy, why not use divs to show hide sections of the page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an class with properties for each form field then store it in the session.  Then after you populate what you need on page 3 remove it from the session.

Example

Class:

```
 <Serializable()>
Public Class Input
    Private _FirstName As String = String.Empty
    Private _LastName As String = String.Empty

    Public Property FirstName As String
        Get
            Return _FirstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _FirstName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LastName As String
        Get
            Return _FirstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _FirstName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Storing data:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim FormData As New Input()
    FormData.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text
    FormData.LastName = txtLastName.Text
    Session("InputData") = FormData
```

End Sub

Retrieving it:

```
   If Not IsNothing(Session("InputData")) Then
       Dim FormData As Input = DirectCast(Session("InputData"), Input)
       txtFirstName.Text = FormData.FirstName
       txtLastName.Text = FormData.LastName
       Session.Remove("InputData")
   End If
```

Comment: any chance you could post a small code sample of how i'd do this. i've looked into it but it's still a little fuzzy. thanks.

Comment: Updated with an example your you

Comment: hey Mike, i appreciate your help but i couldn't get this to work. could you take a look at my code and tell me if you notice anything wrong with it please?

http://i.imgur.com/GiF1T.png -- (Input.vb)
http://i.imgur.com/sDLuR.png -- (Default.aspx)
http://i.imgur.com/8Vggx.png -- (Default.aspx.vb)
http://i.imgur.com/EzhF8.png -- (Default2.aspx) 
http://i.imgur.com/Hqgiy.png -- (Default2.vb)

Comment: You have the postbackURL set to default2.aspx.  remove that and just add response.redirect("~/default2.aspx") before the end of the btnSubmit_Click sub int the default.aspx codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the button.postbackurl property to post the data to another page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx

In the intermediary pages, you could store the data in hidden fields from page 1, so the data would be in the posted results for page 3, when another button posts the data from page 2 to page 3.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much sums up your choices:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would store the values in hidden input fields on page 2 and if page 3 is called as a form submit, then the values will be available through Request.Form.

Comment: when i run this, i get -- __EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE etc, etc.. and then finally, hiddenInput=myValue. i just want the 'myValue'.

Comment: use Request.Form["hiddeninput"] and you will get myvalue